# Adding custom data to RC file in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, embedded-resource

When I create new *.rc file in visual studio and import some custom resource types in it, visual studio include "resources.h" and some directives implicitly in *rc file.

I want create Plain RC file to add custom type binary data only. later I can build  it to embed with application.

But each time I have to manually remove "directives and included headers" from *.rc before compilation.

Is there any way, so I create new *rc file and add any coustom data without adding any include files and directives in visual studio?

I can locally create *.rc file and add any data like i edit text file.
But I want to create using visual studio.

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in fighting the resource editor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the Visual Studio Express can let you add .rc files.

But you can go Project->Add New Item...->Visual C++->Code->C++ File (.cpp)

and change the file name to app.rc.

After that, Right-Click the app.rc file and select View Code.

Now, you can edit it like a text file.

Support Link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: but after adding custom resources to this app.rc it again puts some headers and directives in rc file.

Comment: I think you can delete all of that, just put what you really need in the .rc file

Comment: And I think you didn't really delete the app.rc with some headers and directives, Right-Click app.rc -> Remove -> Delete. And try it again, I think it'll be a clean .rc file now.

Comment: with Remove->Delete option, it deletes only resources added. not the header files and some resources. after deletion ,*.rc  has content like                    #include "resource.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

Comment: How about this, you add a empty app.cpp file (make sure it's empty). And change it to app.rc, I think it will be a complete clean file.